# understanding openweather api response

Tags: api, utc, weather

I'm having trouble interpreting the response from the openweather api. I don't have a clear understanding of the values being returned in the call below.

*the appid is the sample from openweather, not my own

http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=91001&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Particularly dt, but also the day, and min.

```
{
  dt: 1519070400,
  temp: {
   day: 283.99,
   min: 271.86,
   etc...
}
```

These are the definitions of these values from the API

dt - Time of data forecasted temp.day - Day temperature. Unit Default: Kelvin, Metric: Celsius, Imperial: Fahrenheit.

My questions are...

1) I think the dt unit is some kind of utc number, but when I try to do conversions on it using UTC converters, it returns invalid. I can't find more info in the docs on what this is aside from the definition. What is this unit and do you have tips on how to convert it?

2) temp.day - reading the definition I assume it is the temperature today returned in Kelvin, but when I convert it to Fahrenheit, the temperature is off by a significant margin. For this example the zip code is Pasadena, California where the current temperature is 70 degrees F, but when I convert the returned result of 283.99 Kelvin to Fahrenheit the result is 51 degrees. Do you know what this may be?

Any help is appreciated as I try to get better at understanding these types of api responses

Answer (score 2):

1. To convert a UNIX Timestamp to a JavaScript Date object take it times 1000 in the constructor.

   `var date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);`
2. Not knowing what conversion you used it's difficult to debug. If you want to leave the response as Kelvin. be sure to use the following conversion.

   `var fahrenheitTemp = (kelvinTemp − 273.15) × 9/5 + 32;`

   Otherwise you can just pass the units query like so.

   `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=91001&appid=xxxxxx&units=imperal`

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for the delayed. Anyways, i hope that this will be helpful!

1) Please use this converter: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/utime/kpcibgnngaaabebmcabmkocdokepdaki
In it's settings choose the GMT  (Weastern Europe Time, London.....) So the converting will be made according UTC 0000 timezone.
Converts UNIX timestamps to human-readable dates and vice versa.
This is just a timestamp.

2) You use sample file, so it is not connected to the real API service! The real url of API is the following:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=91001&appid=xxxxxx

The url is for 16 daily API which is not available for Free account, so you may not able to access data if you still use Free plan.
The temperature is provided in Kelvins. There is possibility to change units (units=metrics - for C / units=imperal - for F ).